# Value of type '[Root]' has no member 'commit'. How can i decode JSON root array

Tags: ios, json, swift, git, codable

I am trying to parse JSON using codable. I am able to decode it but it is in a root array and i am unable to print each value on by it self. the compiler is complaining saying `Value of type '[Root]' has no member 'commit'`. How can i change this to print the values. Below is the JSON

```
[
    {
        "sha": "3f4227ec2894bb354b145deff9dbc1adc6b6d6f2",
        "node_id": "MDY6Q29tbWl0NDQ4Mzg5NDk6M2Y0MjI3ZWMyODk0YmIzNTRiMTQ1ZGVmZjlkYmMxYWRjNmI2ZDZmMg==",
        "commit": {
            "author": {
                "name": "Slava Pestov",
                "email": "sviatoslav.pestov@gmail.com",
                "date": "2018-08-12T08:09:22Z"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "sha": "3f4227ec2894bb354b145deff9dbc1adc6b6d6f2",
        "node_id": "MDY6Q29tbWl0NDQ4Mzg5NDk6M2Y0MjI3ZWMyODk0YmIzNTRiMTQ1ZGVmZjlkYmMxYWRjNmI2ZDZmMg==",
        "commit": {
            "author": {
                "name": "Slava Pestov",
                "email": "sviatoslav.pestov@gmail.com",
                "date": "2018-08-12T08:09:22Z"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I decode it here

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let commit: Author
}

struct Author: Decodable {
    let author: People
}

struct People: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let date: String?
    let email: String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getCommits()
    }


    func getCommits() {
        let urlString = "https://api.github.com/repos/apple/swift/commits"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Couldn't fetch JSON")
            return
        }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard data != nil && error == nil else {
                print(data ?? "")
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let result = try decoder.decode([Root].self, from: data!)
                print(result.commit)
                print(result.commit.author.name)
            } catch let decodeError {
                print("Failed to decode json:", decodeError)
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

And here is my output in the console. I would like to be able to print only the name, date and email.

> [Gihhub.Commits(commit: Gihhub.Author(author: Gihhub.People(name: Optional("Slava Pestov"), date: Optional("2018-08-12T08:09:22Z"), email: Optional("sviatoslav.pestov@gmail.com")))), Gihhub.Commits(commit: Gihhub.Author(author: Gihhub.People(name: Optional("Slava Pestov"), date: Optional("2018-08-12T03:47:22Z"), email: Optional("spestov@apple.com")))), Gihhub.Commits(commit: Gihhub.Author(author: Gihhub.People(name: Optional("Slava Pestov"), date: Optional("2018-08-12T03:47:08Z"), email: Optional("spestov@apple.com"))))]

Comment: The naming of your structs  is a bit confusing. It's supposed to be `struct Root: Decodable {  let commit: Commit }` `struct Commit: Decodable { let author: Author }` `struct Author: Decodable { let name: String; let date: String; let email: String }`. All struct members can be non-optional. And you can decode `date` as `Date` if you add the date decoding strategy `.iso8601`

Comment: PS: Please watch [WWDC 2017 Session 212 : What's new in Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212) from 24:00. You will see very familiar stuff.

Comment: @vadian thank you very much man, i have watched it and improved my code. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

result is an array you need

```
result.forEach {
    print($0.commit.author.name)
    print($0.commit.author.date)
    print($0.commit.author.email)
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Forgot to loop through. It works perfect.